# How can I center my menu items?

Tags: html, menu, hyperlink, center

I'm a novice, trying to create my own website. I have a menubar on top of the page, and I'd like the menu items to be centered instead of left-justified. Please note: I'm trying to center 2 things. First is the text within the menu item, and the second is the entire group of menu items.

The link is located here:
http://www.martyversusaig.com

My menu-bar code is here:

```
<ul id="nav">
<li id="nav-home"><a href="http://www.martyversusaig.com">Home</a></li>
<li id="nav-about"><a href="http://www.websitegoodies.com/guestbook.php?a=view&amp;id=1045057" target="&rdquo;_blank&rdquo;">Your Story</a></li>
<li id="nav-archive"><a href="http://www.martyversusaig.com/fllaw.html">Florida Law</a></li>
<li id="nav-lab"><a href="#">Lab</a></li>
<li id="nav-reviews"><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
<li id="nav-contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I've tried entering 'center' html tags, but it doesn't center anything and really fouls up the menu.

Any help is greatly apprecaited!

Thanks,
Marty

Comment: I wouldn't use the `li` tags at all but use `div` instead. `li` is really for doing a vertical list, often with bullets or numbers or indicator.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a fiddle of your nav bar so you can see how it would work. You can access it here: http://jsfiddle.net/BQj3P/

To center the `#nav` element, the easiest thing to do is to wrap it in a div. Creat a `#nav-wrapper` element and style it in the same way as you had previously styled `#nav`:

```
#nav-wrapper {  
    margin:0;   
    padding:0;
    background:#808259 url(nav_bg.jpg) 0 0 repeat-x;    
    width:100%; 
    float:left; 
    border:1px solid #42432d;
    text-align: center;
}
```

You'll notice one important difference: `text-align: center`. This will help you center the `#nav` ul.

The `#nav` itself is now styled like this:

```
#nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The `display: inline-block` was the final piece you needed to center the entire set of navigation buttons.

To center the text inside the buttons themselves, your original code had this line to style the #nav list items: `padding:20px 40px 4px 10px;`

In other words, the right padding was set to 40px and the left was set to 10px. Simply changing the line to `padding:20px 20px 4px 20px;` will center your text.

Check out the fiddle for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to use css. I have a separate style sheet.

You will want to nest  so that the outside one centers all elements inside of it and then internal menu items have a specific width, so they don't end up all together.

```
<div class="centre">        
            <div class="block">
                <li id="nav-home"><a href="http://www.martyversusaig.com">Home</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class="block">
                <li id="nav-about"><a href="http://www.websitegoodies.com/guestbook.php?a=view&amp;id=1045057" target="&rdquo;_blank&rdquo;">Your Story</a></li>
            </div>
```

MY CSS:

```
.centre
{
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
    width: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I would lose the `li` altogether and just use `div`. Set up the CSS accordingly.

Comment: You can´t put div elements around li. li-elements must be direct children of an ul.